# Flutter, Admob, suddenly ads are not showing

Tags: flutter, admob, firebase-admob

firstly my interstitialAd occurs error like this

```
W/flutter ( 1924): onAdFailedToLoad: 2
I/Ads     ( 1924): Ad failed to load : 2
I/flutter ( 1924): InterstitialAd event MobileAdEvent.failedToLoad
I/flutter ( 1924): Interstitial failed to load
```

and the bannerAd occurs error like this

```
[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(load_failed_ad,
cannot reload a failed ad, id=674080682, null)
```

I published app before 2months ago and until before 2weeks ago, it has been worked totally fine

but suddenly ads don`t show and now only testAds working fine.

actually my admob stopped like for two days the reason was invalid traffic

(which wasn`t supposed to understand because we didn`t click ads or watching)

and the stopping issue is solved now but since then,

I guess it never shows now

could anyone help this issue please?

and I searched it but everyone says like check the internet

(my internet is totally fine)

Comment: error code 2 means bad connection. maybe your ISP blocked the AdMob AD provider's IP.

Comment: @vegafish but if I have a bad connection then why ohter people also can`t see? on other devices?

Comment: another reason of getting error code 2 is your app generate too many AD requests at the same time. maybe you have to handle a AD-request-completed list to resolve this. ref: https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-android-examples/issues/60#issuecomment-288134167

Comment: @vegafish thanks a lot is there any way to prevent too much requests in flutter admob??

Answer (score 0):

The error thrown from AdMob seems to come from the traffic of requests. Check if the Ad is being loaded multiple times using the `AdListener.onAdLoaded()` callback. This is a known issue as mentioned in this [thread](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-flutter/issues/155).